# If it is not possible that p is not possible in K, does it follow that p is possible in K?

Tags: logic, modal-logic, philosophy-of-logic

I have the following question.

If it is not possible that p is not possible in K, does it follow that p is possible in K?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you specify what p and K are? What does "possible in K" mean? Do you have possible worlds in mind?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. p is a variable; K is a logical system

Comment: If (false && (false)) return true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that does not follow within K. You are giving as a premise, it is not possible that it is not possible that P, i.e.

¬◇¬◇P

From this it follows by the equivalence of ¬◇¬ to □

□◇P

But in K, this does not entail ◇P. It fails to hold because without axiom T, you cannot derive φ from □φ. Within the frame condition of K, a countermodel exists when there there is a world with no worlds accessible to it, not even itself.

Answer (score 0):

If *K* is closed (and does not include, under itself, sentences referring to *K* as a whole), then the "is/not possible" of the outer layer of the sentence will not be the same as the "is/not possible" of the inner layer. So consider:

1. (In *K*) it is not possible<sub>1</sub> that it is not possible<sub>1</sub> that *p*.
2. Therefore, in *K*, *p* is possible<sub>1</sub>.
3. If *K* is possible<sub>2</sub>, then *p* is possible<sub>2</sub>.
4. If *K* is not possible<sub>2</sub>, then *p* is not possible<sub>2</sub>.

I'm not sure about (4) (I feel like there's a bit of an "affirming the consequent" danger in its expression, like if some different system, *L*, is possible<sub>2</sub> and *p* is possible<sub>1</sub> in *L*, then *p* might be possible<sub>2</sub> because of *L*).

For better relevant analysis, see Dominic Gregory, ["Iterated Modalities, Meaning, and A Priori Knowledge"](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/p/phimp/3521354.0011.003/--iterated-modalities-meaning-and-a-priori-knowledge?view=image) as well as Timothy Williamson, ["Counterpossibles in Metaphysics"](http://media.philosophy.ox.ac.uk/assets/pdf_file/0010/37756/Counterpossiblesmetaphysics.pdf).